# thousands of lines in package-lock.json

Tags: npm, package-lock.json

I have 32 thousands of lines in my package-lock.json while in package.json I have only 31 dependencies.

Is it normal to have so many lines in package-lock.json?

I tried deleting node modules and package-lock.json but whenever I run npm i it installs all again.

Comment: dependencies have  their own dependencies so the dependency tree can be quite a lot larger than the direct dependencies.

Comment: It is completely normal for package-lock to be that big as it is containing the exact details of each package and the sub packages that your main packages depend on . Hope that is not confusing :)